# My Linked List Program won't work

Tags: c, pointers, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to create a program that reads in a text file with the following format:

```
Smith, John    
Johnson, Harry    
Clark, David
```

(This can go on endlessly and there doesn't need to be an empty line between each name I just wrote it this way for clarity)

Each line of the text file holds a: `last name` , `first name`. The linked list should store each first and last name as a name node. I believe my general architecture should work, however, as the program executes, it seems that variables such as `pCurrent` and `pHead` are being over-ridden without ever being reassigned. I'm left with a messed up Linked List and I've never seen anything like it. Can anyone spot a flaw in my architecture or anything else that is causing this program not to work as expected. Thanks

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>

struct nameNode {
    char* first;
    char* last;
    struct nameNode* pNext;
    struct nameNode* pPrev;
};

struct nameNode* pHead, *pLast;
char firstName[50], lastName[50];

void insert_end(char* first, char* last) {
    struct nameNode* var = NULL, *temp = NULL;

    var = (struct nameNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct nameNode));

    var->first = first;
    var->last = last;
    if (pHead == NULL) {
        pHead = var;
        pHead->pPrev = NULL;
        pHead->pNext = NULL;
        pLast = pHead;
    } else {
        pLast = pHead;
        while (pLast != NULL) {
            temp = pLast;
            pLast = pLast->pNext;
        }

        pLast = var;
        temp->pNext = pLast;
        pLast->pPrev = temp;
        pLast->pNext = NULL;
        printf("Phead is %s\n", pHead);
    }
}

int main() {
    char file[100];
    printf("Enter input file ");
    scanf("%s", file);
    FILE* in_file = fopen(file, "r");

    while (fscanf(in_file, "%s %s", lastName, firstName) != EOF) {
        insert_end(lastName, firstName);
    }
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Copy those three names into a text file and then write the address when prompted and examine the linked list. That is a complete example, right? Also I can add a print statement to inform the programmer what the pHead is equal to every iteration of the while loop if this will help the problem become more obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You read your name into a global variable and store the *address* of where you read it in to. Then, you read a new name into the same variable -- and so you store the same address again.

Change this in your `insert_end` code

```
var->first = strdup (first);
var->last = strdup (last);
```

to store *copies* of the strings read into `firstName` and `lastName`.

---

Minor: as it is, you actually have *undefined behavior*. You check if `pHead` is NULL, but you never initialize it. Make sure to set it to NULL before calling `insert_end`, or simply initialize it as

```
struct nameNode* pHead = NULL, *pLast = NULL;
```

Also minor: adding a node without a `temp` can be done the following way. In fact, you don't need a loop because you already know that `pLast` points to the end of the list -- but if you want to make sure it's valid, you can make use of the fact that for the last `nameNode` its member `pNext` *must* be NULL:

```
pLast = pHead;
while (pLast->pNext != NULL) {
    pLast = pLast->pNext;
}
pLast->pNext = var;
pLast->pNext->pPrev = pLast;
pLast->pNext->pNext = NULL;
pLast = pLast->pNext;
```

Also minor: to get rid of the comma, insert this near the start in `insert_node`:

```
if (first && first[0] && first[strlen(first)-1] == ',')
    first[strlen(first)-1] = 0;
```

Note that this removes the comma from the argument *called* `first`, which in fact is the last name. You might want to correct that throughout your code.

Also also minor: your `scanf` is not very safe or error-resilient. It may read beyond the storage space for each string (49 characters) and you are checking for an end-of-file but not for an argument count mismatch.

This should be better:

```
while ( fscanf(in_file, " %49[^,],%49s", lastName, firstName) == 2) {
    insert_end(lastName, firstName);
}
```

-- as an added bonus, it also reads-then-ignores the comma.

Comment: Life Saver, thanks so much. So to recap, the problem was a variable scope thing?

Comment: Yup, that was the main thing (although I would not call it "scope"). Make sure to read my minor notes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to define your nameNode structure as following:

```
struct nameNode {
  char[some_size] first; 
  char[some_size] last;
  struct nameNode* pNext;
  struct nameNode* pPrev;
};
```

Or malloc space for the first and last when insert the node.

Comment: That, on itself, does not fix it, although it *could*. You may want to indicate what other changes need to be made.